# Invariance of mutual information under invertible mapping

Tags: reference-request, information-theory

If it is true then is there a reference of the fact that for discrete RVs X and Y the mutual information is invariant to the invertible mapping i-e 
$I(X;Y)=I(X';Y')$ where $X'=h(X)$ and $Y'=g(Y)$ with $h$ and $g$ are invertible functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an almost trivial observation. Due to the invertible mappings considered, the random variables $X$, $X'$, $(X, X')$ are equivalent in terms of entropy as well as information they provide about $Y$ (or, equivalently, $Y'$, $(Y,Y')$).

A bit more formally, it holds
$$
\begin{align}
I(X;Y) &= I(X, X'; Y, Y')\\
&=H(X,X')-H(X,X'|Y,Y')\\
&=H(X')-H(X'|Y')\\
&=I(X';Y')
\end{align}
$$

The steps are intuitive, but you may want to explicitly prove them by computing the standard entropy expressions using the (joint) probability distributions of the quantities involved.